# Endpoint Disabled exception returned from AWS SNS when trying to send Push Notifications with Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS to send push notifications to the mobile app built with ionic. Despite the fact that most of the times sending push notifications works perfectly, in some cases the push notification wasn’t sent and it displayed  the same error(exception):

> Aws\Sns\Exception\EndpointDisabledException Endpoint is disabled

Is there a way to re enable endpoint to AWS SNS after getting Endpoint disabled exception when trying to use Send Push Notifications with Ionic App?

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the error and resolved it.

It was because sometimes the tokens where mixed when they were sending to multiple devices logged with the same user account.